# Hibernate SQLQuery: Database view with multiple entities and aliased column names

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to select multiple classes at once using a database view. Both tables have similar columns, like "ID". Therefore the view is working with aliases.
Unfortunately Hibernate doesn´t map die "ID"-Field properly.

Here a simplified example:

```
Species                 Cat
| ID | Name         |   | ID | Name         | SpeciesId
+----+--------------+   +----+--------------+---------
| 1  | Tuxedo cat   |   | 1  | Sylvester    | 1
                        | 2  | Sylvester Jr | 1
                        | 3  | Sylth Vester | 1
```

These tables could result in the following View

```
CREATE VIEW 'CatsBySpecies' AS
  SELECT
    SPECIES.ID, 
    SPECIES.NAME,
    CAT.ID AS CAT_ID,
    CAT.NAME AS CAT_NAME
  FROM SPECIES 
    LEFT JOIN CAT ON CAT.SPECIESID = SPECIES.ID;
```

The result of the query is correct:

```
|ID| Name     | CAT_ID | CAT_NAME     |
+--+----------+--------+--------------+
|1 |Tuxedo cat|    1   | Sylvester    |
|1 |Tuxedo cat|    2   | Sylvester Jr |
|1 |Tuxedo cat|    3   | Sylth Vester |
```

So far, so good.

Hibernate Query:

```
String select = "Select * from CatsBySpecies";

catQuery = persistentSession.createSQLQuery(select).addEntity(Species.class).addEntity(Cat.class);
Iterator<?> pairs = catQuery.list().iterator();
```

But the classes are not mapped correctly, the result-tuples look like this

```
   Species:               Cat:
      ID = 1               ID = 1
      Name = Tuxedo cat    Name = Tuxedo cat
```

So hibernate seems to recognize the corresponding columnnames and compares them to the object-attributes.

Is there a way to tell hibernate the way to map the aliases?
Unfortunately the tables have much more columns, so I tried to avoid to addScalar for each column of the database-result.

Looking forward to your hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue through adaption of my selection string. 
In this case it is important to use the `{}` form (mentioned also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506732/returning-multiple-object-types-using-hibernate-using-an-inner-join))

In addition I had to announce the aliased column names.
The new selection string looks like this:

```
String select = "Select id as {spec.id}, name as {spec.name}, cat_id as {cat.id}, cat_name as {cat.name} from CatsBySpecies";
```

Now we can get the objects as usual:

```
catQuery = persistentSession.createSQLQuery(select).addEntity("spec", Species.class).addEntity("cat", Cat.class);
```

I hope this helps anyone else out there, who´s facing the same problem.