# Hibernate sql query has two same tables and is expected to return colums that have same name but different values , but it returns same value

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have to return two app name source and target so i am joining the application table to get the the name.. Below is the source code. When I run it I get the following query

```
select distinct app_source,target,zao.app_name,dependency,zat.app_name from zapp_dependency zd join zapplication zao on zao.csi_id=zd.app_source 
join zapplication zat on zat.csi_id=zd.target
```

which when i run in oracle sql developer i get the desired result i.e. the source and target app name as different but in hibernate i get them as same.. Can someone please help?

```
try
    {
    Session session=HibernateUtil.currentSession();

    String sql="select distinct app_source,target,zao.app_name,dependency,zat.app_name from zapp_dependency zd join zapplication zao "
            + "on zao.csi_id=zd.app_source"
            + " join zapplication zat on zat.csi_id=zd.target ";
    ob=session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();
     
    for(Object[] ab:ob)
    {
        ZAppDependencyDTO elem=new ZAppDependencyDTO();
        elem.setSource(ab[0]==null?"":ab[0].toString());
        elem.setTarget(ab[1]==null?"":ab[1].toString());
        elem.setDependency(ab[3]==null?' ':ab[3].toString().trim().charAt(0));
        elem.setId(elem.getSource()+"@@@"+elem.getTarget()+"@@@"+elem.getDependency());
        elem.setSourcename(ab[2]==null?"":ab[2].toString());
        
        System.out.println(ab[2].toString());
        elem.setTargetname(ab[4]==null?"":ab[4].toString());
        System.out.println(ab[4].toString());
dto.add(elem);
    }
    }
    
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        count=0;
        ex.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use alias for the same column name of two table.

```
select distinct app_source,target,zao.app_name as zao_app_name ,zat.app_name as zat_app_name ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be problem with same column name in in two tables

Also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506732/returning-multiple-object-types-using-hibernate-using-an-inner-join)

Could you try with below, giving specific alias name using `{}`

```
String sql="select distinct app_source,target,source_name as {zao.app_name},dependency,target_name as {zat.app_name} from zapp_dependency zd join zapplication zao "
            + "on zao.csi_id=zd.app_source"
            + " join zapplication zat on zat.csi_id=zd.target ";
```

Comment: Thnks a lot for the concept thought the query didnot work but it helped me in solving my problem

Comment: There is this HQL and also native query and could be the reason why the query is didn't work. but good you have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my query to

```
String sql="select distinct app_source,target,zao.app_name as source_name,dependency,zat.app_name as target_name from zapp_dependency zd join zapplication zao "
            + "on zao.csi_id=zd.app_source"
            + " join zapplication zat on zat.csi_id=zd.target "
```

and it worked basically aliasing